# webhook response with django channel's AsyncHttpConsumer on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, channel

I am trying to migrate my code from wsgi to use asgi/channel's asyncHttpConsumer. I can get a http_request from diaglogflow. Then I can either use send() or send_response() for response.
I can do something like

```
await self.send_response(200, b'response text', 
    headers=[(b"Content-Type", b"text/plain"),
            ])
```

and my heroku server sends it out normally, but dialogflow does not get anything back.
I have another wsgi application that just uses

```
from django.http import JsonResponse 
...
fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': "server works correctly"}
return JsonResponse(fulfillmentText, safe=False)
```

where this actually returns to dialogflow correctly.

I tried to use JsonResponse on the asgi/channel side but it just gives me an error that just basically say I'm not using send_response correctly.

What do I need to do to convert my response correctly on the asyncHttpConsumer side?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I just needed to convert my dict to bytes using

```
response = json.dumps(mydict).encode('utf-8')
await self.send_response(200, fulfillmentText, headers=[(b"Content-Type", b"text/plain"),])
```